# Admin But Insufficient Access Rights on SlaProcessId in Flow Execution

Tags: visual-workflow, entitlements, insufficient-privileges

**In sandbox, I have a flow with an element that creates an Entitlement.  The SlaProcessId is the Id of an Entitlement Process; an Entitlement needs to lookup to an Entitlement Process for it to be any use:**

[image]

**The flow works perfectly in sandbox.**

**I then successfully deployed the flow and all its dependencies into production.  But there, when executed, I get the following error precisely at the element above:**

[image]

**However, the Entitlement Process' Id is the same in sandbox and production...**

[image]

**And I'm executing the flow myself, as an *Administrator*.**

**Any clues why I can't access this field in an execution of the flow?**

Comment: Can you assign SlaProcess by name instead? Hard coding IDs against best practices though the error you're receiving does not appear to be that directly.

Comment: It turns out that that object is not a given option in a record-lookup element.

Comment: I take it back, yes it is (i.e. as "SlaProcess", not "Entitlement Process")!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better, based on the Entitlement Process Name retrieve SlaProcessId and store it in the variable and finally use that variable during insertion.

Record Lookup, select **SlaProcess** (which is Entitlement Process)

[image: SLAProcess]

Make sure that Entitlement Process is active and you are using correct version.

Secondly, just a note, when you use Entitlement with Case, in the Case object, by default Entitlement,SlaStartDate, SlaExitDate - these fields doesn't have FLS. So you need to manually provide the FLS.

Comment: Unfortunately the Entitlement Process object can't be queried in a flow-record-lookup element, at least not that I see.

Comment: I take it back; yes it can be queried (i.e. listed as "SlaProcess", not "Entitlement Process")!

Comment: yes, just updated my answer